# run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable in c programming

Tags: c

when key in 2, it will come out the 'press any key to continue' and press 2 more times 'enter' key, it should be close the cmd, but when press the 'enter' key, it will pop out run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'user_choice2' was corrupted.

where is the problem?

here is the code

```
do{

    printf("Please key in your choice (1 to start , 2 to exit)\n>>");
    scanf("%s", &user_choice2);
    if (!isdigit(user_choice2))
    {
        printf("");
    }

}
while (!isdigit(user_choice2));
user_choice = atoi(&user_choice2);
```

Comment: How is `user_choice2` defined?

Answer (score 1):

As `user_choice2` is being passed to `isdigit()` I suspect that `user_choice` is a `char`. Use the format specifier `"%c"` to populate a `char`, not `"%s"`. The format specifier `"%s"` will append a null terminator, writing to memory it should not be and corrupting the stack in this case.

However, as `user_choice2` is being passed to `atoi()` store the user input in a `char[]` as `atoi()` requires a null terminated string. Prevent buffer overrun via `scanf()` by specifying the maximum number of characters to read:

```
char user_choice2[2];
scanf("%1s", user_choice2);
```

then query `user_choice2[0]` in subsequent code.

Simpler: directly populate an `int` using `scanf("%d", &user_choice);` where `user_choice` is an `int`. `scanf()` returns the number of successful assignments made which can be used to check the user entered a valid `int`:

```
if (scanf("%d", &user_choice) != 1)
{
    /* Not a valid int, skip input. */
    char ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}
```

---

> may I know how to prevent user key in a int follow by char? e.g 1a

The format `"%n"` can be used to determine the position where processing ended. Use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` (not `scanf()`) to detect this invalid input. For example:

```
char buf[32];
if (fgets(buf, 32, stdin))
{
    int value, pos;
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d%n", &value, &pos) == 1 &&
        pos == strlen(buf) - 1) /* -1 to account for new-line */
    {
        printf("value=%d\n", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: may I know how to prevent user key in a int follow by char?
e.g 1a

Comment: how can I combine together with the user choice?